# again $.noConflict(); issue

Tags: jquery

I have hard times with modification of this code to work with other script containing `$.noConflict();`. Could you guys please have a look and tell what needs to be changed?

I tried several times, but don't want to post my fail codes here since it is probably irrelevant to you anyway...

Forgive such a trivial question, I'm a `jQuery` beginner yet...

```
$(window).load(function() { 

            $('#slides').slides({
                preload: true,
                play: 5000,
                pause: 2500,
                hoverPause: true,
                animationStart: function(current){
                    $('.caption').animate({
                        bottom:-35
                    },100);
                    if (window.console && console.log) {
                    };
                },
                animationComplete: function(current){
                    $('.caption').animate({
                        bottom:0
                    },200);
                    if (window.console && console.log) {

                    };
                },
                slidesLoaded: function() {
                    $('.caption').animate({
                        bottom:0
                    },200);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: use  `jQuery` instead of `$` if `$.noConflict(true);` isn't used. Now better would be to use only one jQuery lib if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really looking for a window load handler, then you can make use of an IIFE to create a short cut to refer `jQuery` as `$`

```
(function ($) {
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('#slides').slides({
            preload: true,
            play: 5000,
            pause: 2500,
            hoverPause: true,
            animationStart: function (current) {
                $('.caption').animate({
                    bottom: -35
                }, 100);
                if (window.console && console.log) {};
            },
            animationComplete: function (current) {
                $('.caption').animate({
                    bottom: 0
                }, 200);
                if (window.console && console.log) {

                };
            },
            slidesLoaded: function () {
                $('.caption').animate({
                    bottom: 0
                }, 200);
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There was "$.noConflict();" in one js document script and there was "jQuery.noConflict()" in another document.. I deleted the "$.noConflict();" line in one document and now it all works fine... any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to rewrite it like this:

```
jQuery(window).ready(function($) {
    ....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

User document ready function properly

```
$(function(){
    // Your code goes here
});
```

This is short hand for document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Your code goes here
});
```

This is a long form of document ready.

You can use either of it, choice is yours.

Comment: this is different event, nothing to do with window onload event. BTW, i don't see how this could fix OP's issue

Answer (score 1):

You've to set `var jQuery = $.noConflict();`. This is a function provided by jQuery because other libraries could also use the dollar sign as variable name or function. In your jQuery code you've to use the var(in my code sample jQuery) instead of the dollar sign. I've post your code with the `$.noConflict()`:

```
var jQuery = $.noConflict();

jQuery(window).load(function() { 
            jQuery('#slides').slides({
                preload: true,
                play: 5000,
                pause: 2500,
                hoverPause: true,
                animationStart: function(current){
                    $('.caption').animate({
                        bottom:-35
                    },100);
                    if (window.console && console.log) {
                    };
                },
                animationComplete: function(current){
                    jQuery('.caption').animate({
                        bottom:0
                    },200);
                    if (window.console && console.log) {

                    };
                },
                slidesLoaded: function() {
                    jQuery('.caption').animate({
                        bottom:0
                    },200);
                }
            });
        });
```

**NOTE:** if you want to use another var as 'jQuery' just change 'jQuery' to the desired variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the issue was also in other scripts so i had to make more changes. In the end i just deleted the $.noConflict(); line...